# Weekwise query : Mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to get data starting from Monday to Sunday
putting below query in where condition selects Jan-11, week 2 but gives data from 10 Jan to 16 Jan.

```
date_format(DATE_ADD(a.timestamp, INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK(a.timestamp))+1 day),
'%b-%d, Week %U') = 'Jan-11, Week 02'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
date_format(a.timestamp, '%u') = '02';
```

If you need Monday to be the first day of week, use '%u' instead of '%U'.

Reference:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

```
%U  Week (00..53), where Sunday is the first day of the week; WEEK() mode 0
%u  Week (00..53), where Monday is the first day of the week; WEEK() mode 1
%V  Week (01..53), where Sunday is the first day of the week; WEEK() mode 2; used with %X
%v  Week (01..53), where Monday is the first day of the week; WEEK() mode 3; used with %x
```

Update:
If the input value must be like the first day of week 'Jan-11, Week 02', we had to modify based on your original clause, still using '%U'. Seems not so elegant, but should work.

```
date_format(DATE_ADD(a.timestamp, INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK( DATE_SUB(a.timestamp, INTERVAL 1 DAY) )) day),'%b-%d, Week %U') = 'Jan-11, Week 02'
```

Comment: thanks but can you advice for this format.
'Jan-11, Week 02'

week starting from Monday to Sunday

Comment: @Priyanshu '%U' starts from Sunday, while '%u' starts from Monday. I updated the post with more info.

Comment: Hi Dylan Su,
thanks for the more infor.

My input in the query will be 'Jan-11,week 02' 
not just '02' in the code.

can you advice date_format to enter 'Jan-11,week 02' which will return records from monday starting from 11'Jan 2016 to next sunday. 

please note : I tried putting  '%b-%d, Week %u'  its not working

Comment: @Priyanshu If so, the simpler clause can't be used. We need to modify based on ur original stmt. I updated the post. Pls let me know if it works.